# _ is not defined when using node-underscorify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, underscore.js, browserify

I am attempting to use node-underscorify with Grunt to compile HTML templates into a format that Underscore will accept.

My gruntfile looks as such:

```
browserify: {
        standalone: {
            src: ['<%= config.main %>/*/*.js'],
            dest: '<%= config.dist %>/js/<%= pkg.name %>.standalone.js',
            options: {
                standalone: '<%= pkg.name %>',
                transform: ['node-underscorify'],
                debug: true,
                external: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone.marionette']
            }
        },
```

All was working well until I tried to use Underscore methods inside HTML templates. For example, trying to call _.each results in a " _ is not defined" error. According to the [node-underscorify documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-underscorify), an require option can be passed in, such as:

```
requires:[{variable: '_', module: 'underscore'}]}
```

How can I properly set up node-underscorify to work with Grunt such that I can use underscore methods in my HTML templates (or view helpers, etc)?

Comment: I think you would be better to create issue for that module. It's hard to tell what's wrong without digging through that module. Its author should be more able to find an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although having second look in the docs, it should be pretty obvious. I think it cannot work like that. Instead you should invoke something like this in your code.

```
document.body.innerHTML = template({message: "Hello Node Underscorify!", _: require('underscore')});
```

Comment: That was exactly it. I chose the wrong part of the documentation to chase. Thank you for your help.